# Error when creating a new migration using TypeORM and NestJs with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs, typeorm

I have a node application using typescript and I'm trying to create a new migration, following the documentation of the TypeORM.

First I installed the [CLI](https://typeorm.io/#/using-cli/installing-cli), set up my connection options like [this](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations/creating-a-new-migration) and when I try to run this command:

`npm run typeorm migration:create -- -n migrationNameHere`
I get the following error:

> Error during migration creation: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
> at Object. (...\src\commands\MigrationCreateCommand.ts:62:37)
> at step (...\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:141:27)
> at Object.throw (...\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:122:57)
> at rejected (...\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:69) npm ERR!
> code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! backend@0.0.1 typeorm: node
> --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js "migration:create" "-n" "migrationNameHere"` npm ERR! Exit status 1

These are my nest dependencies in package.json:

My node version is **v12.14.1**, nestjs is **7.0.0** and nestjs/typeorm is **7.1.3**

My app.module.ts is like this:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: database().host,
      port: parseInt(database().port),
      username: database().username,
      password: database().password,
      database: database().schema,
      entities: [Question, QuestionOption],
      migrations: ['migration/*.js'],
      cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'migration'
      },
      synchronize: true,
    })
```

Does anybody has ever faced this sort of problem?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try to add flag with a destination of a migration such as `npx typeorm migration:create -n YourName -d src/migrations`

Comment: Thanks, the secret was the -d src/migrations, with that, the migration file was created.

One strange thing is that I configured that in the app.module.ts (see migrationDir), where I tried to add src/migration too but the same error happened, but your solution worked pretty well